# Why does Prisma (mongodb) convert <T>? to T | null | undefined?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

Does anyone know why Prisma converts types with ? to type, null or undefined? When it should be type or undefined?

I kept importing the following code throughout my entire app:

```
model Reminder {
  id                String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String @db.ObjectId
  createdAt         DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime @updatedAt
  date              DateTime?
  time              String?
  priority          String
  title             String @unique
  description       String?

  user              User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade )

}
```

Only to have to go back and refactor to this instead:

```
export type Reminder = {
  id?: string;
  userId: string;
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
  date?: Date;
  time?: string;
  priority: string;
  title: string;
  description?: string;
};
```

Why does prisma/mongo do this instead of converting T? to T|undefined|null ?

Comment: In prisma, null and undefined have different meanings. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined If you use the type somewhere else, then you can use variants like `<Model>UncheckedCreateInput` or `<Model>CreateInput`

Comment: Okay I missed that, thanks!